# How to disable module hooks for certain controllers in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm writing my own module and the essential option is to control controller from the module options.

I know how to control tpl and js via module options but I can't get the way to control Prestashop controller from the module php file.

Simply I want to know the way how to do it.

I want to have four checkboxes with options to enable or disable module in four controllers like **index**, **cms**, **category**, **product**.

I have right now:

```
$values = array('index','product','cms','category');
 if(in_array(Tools::getValue('controller'), $values)){
 return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
}
```

And this code display tpl file content in this four controllers in homepage (index), cms, category and the product pages.
But how to put there some trigger to enable/disable values from the array?

Comment: Keep in mind that requests for off site resources are off topic.

Comment: agree @BSMP i have agree with Your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a configuration field for the controllers:

```
public function getContent()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('MY_CONTROLLERS_LIST')) {
        Configuration::updateValue('MY_CONTROLLERS_LIST', (string)Tools::getValue('PS_MY_CONTROLLERS'));
    }

    $value = Configuration::get('MY_CONTROLLERS_LIST');

    return '<form action="" method="POST"><input name="PS_MY_CONTROLLERS" value="'.$value.'"><input type="submit" value="Save"></form>';
}

public function hookDisplayTop()
{
    $value = Configuration::get('PS_MY_CONTROLLERS');
    $controllers = explode(',', $value);

    if(in_array(Tools::getValue('controller'), $controllers)){
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will appear in Modules > Modules > Configure (of your module). There are form helpers which can render PrestaShop forms, but this is simplified example showing that you will need aform that submits to the same page.

Controllers value for this example should be `index,category,cms,product`.

**Another way**

Go to `Modules > Positions` Find your hook (for example `displayTop`) and your module, click `Edit`. Then selected the pages where you don't want to show the block.

**Generating Options Form**

The correct way (but more complicated) would be to generate the form using `HelperForm` or `HelperOptions` classes that come with PrestaShop

Comment: Probably i don't understand this PS_MY_CONTROLLERS. What is it? Look's like MySQL table name? So in this manner we create table PS_MY_CONTROLLERS with values entered in input field - in this case if i enter there "category" the mymodule.tpl will be displayed only in "category" controller yes? I know about this "another way" but i want be able to control the controllers via module :)

Comment: Must say that was so easy! Answer approved! Now i need to find a way to change input to checkboxes ;). Anyway good job @gskema

Comment: `PS_MY_CONTROLLERS` is a key (you can it whatever you want) in `ps_configuration` table. Every key has a value. Check this table in the database to see what kind of information is store there. Our value for this keye is a string, list of controllers: `"index,category,cms,product"`. When we need to use it, we grab the string and the split it by `,`

Comment: The correct way (but more complicated) would be to generate the form using `HelperForm` or `HelperOptions` classes that come with PrestaShop.